Proving there can be no Killing form on the Virasoro algebra
For the past few days I've been studying the concepts of Lie algebras. Currently I'm busy with real Lie algebras and real forms. I stumbled upon an exercise which I'm really struggling with, it goes as follows: Consider the Virasoro algebra which is generated by the generators K and $L_n$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. The Lie brackets are given by
$$[L_n,K] = 0 \\
[L_n,L_m] = (n-m)L_{n+m} + \frac{1}{12}n(n^2-1)\delta_{n+m,0}K$$
I now must proof that there cannot exist a symmetric invariant form k on this algebra. I followed the hints suggested by the author, which told me that I first had to check that $k(K,...) = 0$, by using the invariance property of the form on $k([K,L_n],L_m)$. So I did this in the following way. First of al since $[K,L_n] = 0$,$k([K,L_n],L_m) = 0$. From this I conclude that
$$0 = k([K,L_n],L_m) = k(K,[L_n,L_m]) = (n-m)k(K,L_{n+m}) + \frac{1}{12}n(n^2 - 1)\delta_{n+m,0}k(K,K)$$
Now in the solution I have it states that
$$0 = k([K,L_n],L_m) = k(K,[L_n,L_m]) = (n-m)k(K,L_{n+m})$$
and that therefore $k(K,L_j) = 0$ for all $j \in \mathbb{Z}$. I really do not see how this jump happens from what I have got. Does anybody have a tip in order to proceed?

From what I can see, everything is fine unless $n=-m$, so we are left with that case. Then we have
$$0=k([K,L_n],L_{-n})=k(K,[L_n,L_{-n}])=2n\cdot k(K,L_0)+n(n^2-1)\cdot k(K,K)/12.$$
Now set $n=1$ to obtain $0=2\cdot k(K,L_0)$, as needed.
In general, I would fix $n=1$ and let $m$ vary  to obtain all $L_j$ (except $j=2$...) in the first term and eliminate the second term entirely.

ooow I see thank you very much for your help :))
